# containstable searching for multiple words

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql query

```
SELECT *
FROM Search..searchProducts AS sp 
INNER JOIN
   CONTAINSTABLE(searchProducts , [description], '5 red rover') AS sp2
   ON sp2.[KEY] = sp.group_id
   WHERE sn2.RANK > 2
ORDER BY sn2.RANK DESC;
```

i'm getting error however i'm trying to get the first query to run like second

```
select * from search..searchProduct where description like '%5 red rover%'
```

any help would be great thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "do it straight"?

Comment: my bad typo second query pulls back the data i want i'm trying to get the top query to get the same data back

Comment: @Neo What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Syntax error near 'red' in the full-text search condition '5 red rover'.

Comment: I think you just need `CONTAINSTABLE(searchProducts , [description], '"5 red rover"')`

Comment: tried its not pulling back the right data looks like the number is messing with the containstable